# is_numeric não funciona com separador decimal ,

Tags: php

Estou utilizando a  função `is_numeric` no caso abaixo não funciona.
Por exemplo, se `$val = 0,2` quero que mude para 0.2

Só para contextualizar os outros valores poderiam ser:

1. uma cadeia de caracteres => nesse caso quero que fique apenas entre
   aspas simples: 'exemplo'.
2. vazio => Se tiver vazio quero que apareça aspas simples vazias  **''**

Obs.: Já tentei:
`if (is_numeric($val){}`

```php
foreach ($innerArray as $key=>$val) {

    if (is_numeric($val)){
        $val = str_replace(",", ".", $val);
        $aux .= $val . ",";
    } else {
        $aux .="'" . $val ."'" . ",";
    }
}
```

Comment: **0,2** é uma string por ter uma vírgula. `is_numeric` não vai funcionar.

Comment: Então a questão seria: Como posso pegar os valores com virgula. Somente os que são números e transformá-los para Number.

Comment: Há outros valores com vírgula e que não são tratados como números?

Comment: Podem existir textos ou qualquer outra coisa. Nessa aplicação que estou desenvolvendo eu não sei qual é o tipo de dado que chega. Daí o problema. Por exemplo, se chegar: [Ola, Tudo bem! ] => quero que apenas fique em aspas simples. Se chegar vazio [] =>quero colocar aspas simples. Se chegar: [0,2] => quero mudar para [0.2]

Comment: No PHP dados numéricos utilizam o padrão americano, onde o separador decimal é o ponto. Você precisa alterar o input de `,` para `.` antes de entrar no `is_numeric`

Comment: Creio que terá que fazer isso usando regex.

Comment: Também acho que será por ai... to pesquisando aqui como seria com o preg_replace. Se alguém tiver uma dica posta ai ;)

Comment: Essa string numerica é delimitada somente por virgula?

Comment: De onde vem esse valor ao certo ?

Comment: Bruno, por favor, edite a pergunta para acrescentar detalhes: é clicar em [edit] logo abaixo das tags e atualizar seu post. Valeu!

Comment: usando a regex '\d+,\d+' não atende seu problema? Assim, quando o array resultante dela vier vazio, significa que não há números separados por virgula, bastando você trocar pelas aspas.

Comment: Essa string numerica é delimitada somente por virgula?

Comment: @brunoNascimento adicionei uma resposta. Veja se irá lhe ajudar.

Comment: `is_numeric()` não é um método de conversão, é usado para verificar se é um número, ele retorna o booleano `true` caso seja número, ou `false` caso não seja um número.

Comment: para converter para número use: `intval($sua_string_numerica)` para inteiros, e `floatval($sua_string_numerica)` para um float.

Answer (score 1):

Junta o `number_format()` com o `is_numeric` - podes depois usar o [`number_format`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) com argumentos para fazer disso o formato que queres. [exemplo](https://3v4l.org/5MXYR)

```
$number = '1,2';
echo is_numeric(number_format($number));


$number = ['1,2', 1, ''];
foreach ($number as $val) {
    if (!empty($val) || !ctype_alnum($val)) echo "val: $val is_numeric ".is_numeric(number_format($val))."\n\r";
}
```

Podes ainda, simplesmente, remover tudo o que seja letra e deixar só os numeros *antes* de fazeres o foreach:

```
$number = 'abc1,2def';
$number = preg_replace(/[a-zA-Z]/i, '', $number);
echo 'is numeric? '.is_numeric(number_format($number));
```

Answer (score 1):

### Considerações

Bom, primeiramente vou fazer algumas considerações perante a lógica de validação implementada em sua aplicação, depois focarei na resolução do seu problema. Você decidirá qual é mais conveniente.

#### Regras de entrada.

Toda aplicação é preciso ter regras de entrada. É tal da validação de entradas de usuário, tudo que ele digitar é preciso impor validação.

Levando em consideração que este valor seja uma entrada de usuário e sua aplicação venha a precisar entender essa entrada como `INT` será necessário validar, não efetuar cálculo sobre a string digitada.

Recomendo fortemente você validar esta entrada na fonte e não transformar o valor para a saída correta, assim sua aplicação processando o valor da entrada do usuário corretamente.

#### Performance

Forçar o usuário a digitar corretamente o valor, como por exemplo:

`float 0.2` invés de `string 0,2` irá melhorar performance da sua aplicação.

Pois assim você não precisará impor uma transformação de [typecast convertion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_conversion).

Economizando custo de performance na aplicação.

#### Bons modos

Segurança é fator primordial, então vamos validar todas entrada de usuário antes de processá-las?

Um simples `if(is_numeric($string))` na entrada do usuário poderá dizer a ele se o valor que ele esta digitando é válido para sua aplicação processar. Assim você impõe regras de validação em sua aplicação.

### Resolução

Caso sua aplicação venha aceitar este tipo de entrada e seja preciso converter-lá para `INT` ou `FLOAT` você poderá fazer das seguintes formas:

Primeiramente vamos dar um **replace** nos caracteres de string.

```
$string = str_replace(',', '.', $string);
```

Depois é só trabalhar com o [floatval()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.floatval.php)

```
$float_value = floatval( $string );
```

Assim irá converter o `typecast` de string para `int`

Ficando assim:

```
$string = '0,2';

$string = str_replace(',', '.', $string);

$float_value = floatval( $string );

var_dump(floatval($float_value));  // 0.2

var_dump(is_numeric($float_value)); // true
```

Desta forma será possível processar entradas como por exemplo: `0,2`, `0.2`, `2`, `-9999` e `2a0` que será entendido como `2`

Answer (score 1):

Para muda sua string para um valor, basta fazer isso, que já irá funcionar:

```
<?php 
function convertNumber($val)
{
   return floatval(preg_replace('/([,])+/','.', $val));
}  

$val = '0,2';
echo convertNumber($val);  

?>
```

Veja aqui o método funcionando:

**http://ideone.com/X7nTyi**

> **Obs:** Utilize o método `is_numeric()` para verificar se é um número e não para convertê-lo. A saída esperada é um booleano para o método e não um número convertido.

Para aplicar no seu laço, aplique o método, porém faça uma verificação se contém um número na sua string para aplicar o método:

```
$values = array();

foreach ($innerArray as $key=>$val) {
     if(is_numeric($val) || preg_match('/[0-9]+/',$val)) {
        $values[] = convertNumber($val);
     } else {
        $values[] = "'{$val}'";
     }
}

$saida = implode(', ', $values);
```